# Changing the Comment Fields using Filter (without success)

Tags: comments, comment-form

Am I doing this all wrong or should this be working? No matter what post I visit, it's thrown into an endless loop..

**This is the code:**

```
add_filter('comment_form_fields', 'comment_form_args');
function comment_form_args( $fields ) {

  if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    comment_form(array(
    'label_submit' => __('Submit for Approval'),
    'comment_notes_before' => '',
    'title_reply' => 'Need to ask something? Go ahead.',
    'title_reply_to' => 'Your reply to %s',
    'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . _x( '', 'noun' ) . '</label><br /><textarea id="comment" name="comment" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>',
    'comment_notes_after' => '<p>Be polite and specific. Spam will be deleted.</p>'
    )
  );
  } else {

    comment_form(array(
    'label_submit' => __('Submit'),
    'comment_notes_before' => '',
    'title_reply' => '',
    'title_reply_to' => 'Answer %s',
    'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . _x( '', 'noun' ) . '</label><br /><textarea id="comment" name="comment" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>',
    'comment_notes_after' => ''
    )
  );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has 2 major issues:

1. It's missing a `return $fields;` or a return value — Filter callbacks must always return something, which is normally the first parameter after it's filtered (regardless it's actually modified or not by your callback).
2. Do not call [`comment_form()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comment_form/) because [`comment_form_fields`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_form_fields/) is fired in that function, hence you'll run into a never-ending loop, just like you've seen it yourself.

And looking at your code which calls `comment_form()`, I believe the hook you should be using is [`comment_form_defaults`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_form_defaults/) and not `comment_form_fields`.

So try the following instead:

```php
// Use comment_form_defaults and not comment_form_fields.
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'comment_form_args' );

function comment_form_args( $args ) {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return array_merge( $args, array(
            'label_submit'         => __( 'Submit for Approval' ),
            'comment_notes_before' => '',
            'title_reply'          => 'Need to ask something? Go ahead.',
            'title_reply_to'       => 'Your reply to %s',
            'comment_field'        => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . _x( '', 'noun' ) . '</label><br /><textarea id="comment" name="comment" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>',
            'comment_notes_after'  => '<p>Be polite and specific. Spam will be deleted.</p>'
        ) );
    } else {
        return array_merge( $args, array(
            'label_submit'         => __( 'Submit' ),
            'comment_notes_before' => '',
            'title_reply'          => '',
            'title_reply_to'       => 'Answer %s',
            'comment_field'        => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . _x( '', 'noun' ) . '</label><br /><textarea id="comment" name="comment" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>',
            'comment_notes_after'  => ''
        ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: PS: If you did want to modify the comment fields like Name and Email, then you can use the `fields` arg to modify the fields, e.g. for the Name field, add `$args['fields']['author'] = 'your code';` before the `return` line.

Comment: Thank you so much Sally! I appreciate you taking the time to answer and for providing some insight and understanding. Thanks.